# Spring Security isn't doing what I thought it would

Tags: spring, security

I'm trying to make it where only admins can view /data. Postman is allowing both user and admin to access it though. Was wondering what I was doing wrong.

```
@EnableWebSecurity
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication()
            .withUser("admin").password("{noop}pw").roles("ADMIN").and()
            .withUser("user").password("{noop}pw").roles("USER");
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
        httpSecurity
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("**/data*").hasRole("ADMIN")
            .and().httpBasic();
        httpSecurity.csrf().disable();
    }
}
```

Admin should be able to access data through `/data` and user shouldn't.

Comment: `**/data` and `/data` don't match... What are the exact URLs you are trying to protect?

Answer (score 0):

Try to change URL in antMatchers to starts from slash and try again.

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
    httpSecurity
        .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/**/data").hasRole("ADMIN")
        .and().httpBasic();
    httpSecurity.csrf().disable();
}
```